# Why does ";C" get added to the end of my strings in bash when running docker on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, bash, docker

I have a bash script that I am trying to run, which includes the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run \
    --env-file .env.local \
    -p ${Z_PORT:-8001}:8000 \
    --entrypoint /bin/bash \
    --hostname forms-api.local \
    --name forms-api \
    --net lasernet \
    --rm \
    --volume "$(pwd)":/opt/application \
    --volume "$(pwd)/logs":/var/log/application \
    dockerhub.zad.com/z-project
```

However, when I use git-bash to run it, I get the following error:

```
The source path "C:/Users/[...]/Documents/GitHub/ZProject;C"
doesn't exist and is not known to Docker.
```

That `;C` definitely shouldn't be there, but the rest is otherwise correct. When I add some like `echo $(pwd)`, the correct path is printed, so it seems to be related to the docker command itself. It also seems to be specific to Windows, as my Mac-using coworkers haven't had any issues running this. What would cause that addition?

Comment: @thatotherguy Oh man, thank you! I couldn't believe that I couldn't find _anyone_ else having the same problem.

Comment: Did the answer on that question solve the problem?

Comment: @thatotherguy Yes, it did, so I've marked this one as a duplicate.